# How to convert curl command to Requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I need to retrieve data from a REST API.

In the Centos shell I can do:

```
 curl -H "ID:1234" -H "Password:ABC" http://url.com/curl
```

I am trying to do this with Requests in Python.

On [the quickstart page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) I see:

```
 payload = {'ID': '1234' , 'Password' : 'ABC' }
 requests.get("http://url.com/curl", params=payload)
```

However this doesn't work. It only returns the status 200, but no data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the `-H` handle for curl, you're setting header values.
In requests, you pass header data the same way you do with the params but you use a different keyword.

```
headers = {'ID': '1234' , 'Password' : 'ABC' }
requests.get("http://url.com/curl", headers=headers)
```

[See Custom Headers from the requests doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

Comment: Is the `response.text` empty or how are you trying to access the response data?

Comment: thanks I tried print response not response.text. It works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open chrome devtools > **Network** panel > right-click on a request > **Copy as curl**.

[image: copy as curl]

Next, paste the curl command into the web form linked below <sup>(I have no affiliation with the site)</sup>

- https://curl.trillworks.com <sup>[[source on github](https://github.com/NickCarneiro/curlconverter)]</sup>

There is also a pip package for this: <sup>(not tested)</sup>

- https://github.com/halilozercan/runcurl