# How do a make this restful api call in python way

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have a curl command as follows that can make a restful API call to my webservice:

```
curl 'https://my-web-service/...'  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: csrftoken=xxx; sessionid=xxx'
```

Now how do I have such command ported in python3 code?

Here is what I have initial coded in python3, which is not working yet.

```
import requests
csrftoken = 'xxx'
sessionid = 'xxx'
api_url = "https://my-web-service/..."
header = {"Cookie": ? }  
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=header)
print(response.status_code)
```

Because I don't know how to fit both sessionid and csrftoken value in the hearder part.  Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Have you tried using the entire Cookie string `csrftoken=xxx; sessionid=xxx` from curl as-is to the headers dict?

Comment: Thanks. That solution does solve my issue. Something as: "cookie_setting = "csrftoken="+csrftoken+";sessionid="+sessionid"  And " header = {"Cookie": cookie_setting} ". But it does not look  neat to me. I thought there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert curl command to Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319470/how-to-convert-curl-command-to-requests)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know what "neat" you are looking for, but if you're concatenating strings, try using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals): `cookie_setting = f"csrftoken={csrftoken}; sessionid={sessionid}"`

Comment: Nice!  I am just a beginner of python. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

[headers](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) can typically be passed as a dictionary via requests.

```
import requests
url = "https://my-web-service/..."
headers = {'Cookie': 'xxx', 'sessionid': 'xxx'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: In my case, both csrftoken and sessionid are under Cookie, they are not the separate one.

Comment: So you have a nested dict? This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818348/how-to-pass-a-nested-dictionary-as-a-header-in-python-requests